# Binary search not working - NON array.

Tags: java, search, binary-search

I'm not sure if this is an issue with my formula or my thought process.  This is an exercise from CodeAbbey so not looking for the specific answer, just a push in the right direction.

I understand binary searches when it comes to array's.  Here we're trying to use it to solve an equation.  This is the example:

```
A * x + B * sqrt(x ^ 3) - C * exp(-x / 50) - D = 0
```

This is my formula where mid serves as x:

```
double result = (((a * mid) + (b * (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mid, 3.0)))) - (c * (Math.exp(-mid / 50)) - d)));
```

This is a test case they give:

Data:

```
1
0.59912051 0.64030348 263.33721367 387.92069617
```

Result should be:

```
73.595368554162
```

I think it's my formula. If I plug in that result I do not get 0 as I assume I should.

Which is why I never get exited from my while loop.

```
package com.secryption.CA34BinarySearch;

import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by bmarkey on 11/11/2015.
 */

public class BinarySearch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Data: ");
        int testCases = scanner1.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++) {
            double a = scanner1.nextDouble();
            double b = scanner1.nextDouble();
            double c = scanner1.nextDouble();
            double d = scanner1.nextDouble();
            boolean solved = false;

            double upperBound = (c + d) / (a + b);
            double lowerBound = 0;
            double mid;

            while (!(solved)) {

                mid = (upperBound + lowerBound) / 2.0;
                double result = ((a * mid) + (b * (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(mid, 3.0)))) - (c * (Math.exp(-mid / 50)) - d));

                if (result > 0) {
                    upperBound = mid;
                } else if (result < 0) {
                    lowerBound = mid;
                } else {
                    System.out.println(mid);
                    solved = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get rid of the extra parentheses, and you'll see that your `- d` term has become incorrectly multiplied by the `c` term.

You'll probably also need to compare to something very close to zero, since in testing this I found that the `result` variable doesn't exactly reach zero because of floating point inaccuracies, i.e:

```
if (Math.abs(result) < 1e-10) {
      System.out.println(mid);
      solved = true;
} else if (result > 0) {
      upperBound = mid;
} else if (result < 0) {
      lowerBound = mid;
}
```

Comment: that worked thanks.  Why was that happening?  I assumed that (Math.exp(-mid / 50)) would calculate, then be multipled by c then d subtracted from that.

Comment: @TheEditor you had the `- d` too far inside the parentheses, i.e. you had `(c * (... - d))` instead of `(c * (...) - d)`

Comment: Ok. Got it.  I knew it was going to be something simple like that. Lesson learned.

Comment: You actually had far too many parens all around - in general for maths expressions the normal rules apply, so you could have just got away with: `result = a * mid + b * Math.pow(mid, 1.5) - c * Math.exp(-mid / 50) - d`   (taking advantage of sqrt(x^3) == x^1.5)

Comment: Good information. I am trying to break that habit of too many parens.  I'm working on it.

Comment: You also need to compare to somthing _close_ to zero, e.g. 1e-10, since floating point math won't converge to exactly zero in this case

Comment: I saw that.  My plan was to round the result.  That way I can compare it to 0.  I'm still learning all the fun of precision decimal math.